# how can i pivot my sql table in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I'm trying to pivot table in bigquery.
I have a table from this query

```
SELECT category, salesRank, productDetail, productId FROM productTable;
```

[image: before pivot image]

But I wanna make like this.

[image: after pivot image]

How can I make a query to show a table like that?

Comment: Since BigQuery doesn't have PIVOT() function. For now, you may use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (aka, Dynamic SQL) for form a query with flexible column. See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct an arrays with what you need pretty easily:

```
select sales_rank,
       array_agg(struct(t.category, t.salesrank, t.productdetail, t.productid) order by min(t.productid) as products
from t
group by sales_rank;
```

You can pivot using conditional aggregation:

```
select sales_rank,
       max(case when category = 'Bag' then salesrank end) as bag_salesrank,
       max(case when category = 'Bag' then productdetail end) as bag_productdetail,
       max(case when category = 'Bag' then productid end) as bag_productid,
       max(case when category = 'Wallet' then salesrank end) as wallet_salesrank,
       max(case when category = 'Wallet' then productdetail end) as wallet_productdetail,
       max(case when category = 'Wallet' then productid end) as wallet_productid,
       . . .
from t
group by sales_rank;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it doesn't work perfectly as i thought, but helps me make a solution.